# ¿Cómo utilizar el sistema de grilla de Bootstrap en Wordpress?

Tags: bootstrap, wordpress, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-3

Buen día;

Quisiera saber cómo utilizo el sistema de grilla de bootstrap en un widget de Wordpress, he intentado añadirlo así dentro del código php de mi widget:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');`

Pero me daña estilos del theme (como menu y fuentes) que tengo actualmente, el theme que tengo se llama **enfold** y utiliza unas grillas con clases como `av_one_third`, pero no me queda responsivo el contenido de mi plugin, ¿Alguien ha intento realizar esto?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que generes un script de Bootstrap que incluya solamente el sistema grid. Puedes hacerlo según se explica en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684023/bootstrap-4-flex-grid-system-only).

Una vez que lo hayas logrado puedes solamente incluir esos estilos para tu widget y no te destruirá el resto de los estilos.

De todas formas en la documentación oficial del tema garantizan que es responsive, si puedes omitir el uso de Bootstrap y aprovechar el estilo que te ofrece el mismo tema, sería la solución ideal.